# Text getting cut off at end on scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've spent most of my day trying a number of solutions to get this to work and I've googled lots of stackoverflow answers yet nothing has helped me. The problem is that I have a lot of text being shown and at the end it gets cut off. I can verify this by going to the end and deleting some of the text as the pieces below show up. I've set my table to have a bigger content size which did increase the scroll area but the text view gets cut off. Below the content size I have set for the scroll area is some methods I have tried but none have worked. Now what is odd is I set up a sizeToFit method as well but it worked once then it stopped working. This worked when I changed the height on the text view I have set up in my storyboard then after that it stopped working. It literally is driving me mad.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
    self.procedureScrollView.contentSize = (CGSizeMake(320, 1800));
    self.procedureText.contentSize = (CGSizeMake(320, 1800));
    self.procedureScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.procedureScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    if (indexPath.row < _procedureVariables.count)
        return 40.0f;
    else {
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n\n %@", [_templateDictionary objectForKey:@"indicationText"], [_templateDictionary objectForKey:@"procedureText"]];
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        return labelSize.height;

}}
```

Here is the viewWillAppear method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.procedureText setFrame:self.procedureTextFrame];
    [self.indicationTextView setFrame:self.indicationTextFrame];

    self.reducedIndicationTextHeight = self.indicationTextView.frame.size.height - 180;
    self.reducedProcedureTextHeight = self.procedureText.frame.size.height - 180;

    self.increasedIndicationTextHeight = self.indicationTextView.frame.size.height + 180;
    self.increasedProcedureTextHeight = self.procedureText.frame.size.height + 180;
    [self.caseDataTableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is the sizeToFit method I used.

```
[self.procedureText sizeToFit];
```

I've tried countless solutions and none have worked. I've put this code into viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad, etc. Nothing has worked. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you use auto layout to layout these Text(UILabel? or UITextView?) in your UIScrollView?

Comment: No, autolayout is turned off.

Comment: If you are adding TextView to ScrollView, it is not recommended by Apple, Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652334/uitextview-inside-uiscrollview-with-autolayout#answer-30633898