# UITextView inside a scrollView with Autolayout iOS not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a dynamic UIView that holds some fixed graphics elements and some dynamic text. I can't find a tutorial, or something in documentation that works for my project. Below is my exploded view (my view with scrollView and main view's height is forced to 800 in iphone 5 view, only for the pourpose of this question)
[image]

What do I want to acheive? The Header,the image,static view and static view 2 are all fixed, and they will not change with their contents. Label 1, Label 2 and the textarea will grow with their content size.

[image]

I have worked on this thing for about a day, and I need a little help because I can't achive any results. I have tried this solution:

[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652334/uitextview-inside-uiscrollview-with-autolayout)

With this solution I can see in NSLog() the textview constraint that return a correct value

```
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = [textview sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textview.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;
```

but the textarea frame at runtime remains the same.

i have tried also this tutorial:

[solution 2](https://medium.com/rocknnull/ios-working-with-uiscrollview-uitextview-and-auto-layout-afa39fe2cac8#.rdtfifvi0)

It works for me in a project with only a scrollview, content view and textview. When i try to use that logic in my project it doesn't work anymore.

I have tried many other solutions, so my questions are: How I can achive the desired result? Or maybe there's something ridiculously wrong in my layout setting? Or simply, is there someone that can point my to a tutorial that cover a similar view organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid having a complex nested subviews inside a `UIScrollView` with AutoLayout, you should instead put them inside a subView. The best thing to start with:

1: Place a single `UIView` inside your `UIScrollView` with `leading`/`trailing`/`top`/`bottom` constraints set to 0 to the `UIScrollView`.

2: Place all the subviews inside the **one single** `UIView`,

3: Once you change the text/dynamic content of any of the subViews inside the `UIView`, you just calculate the `scrollView.contentSize` and set it accordingly by code needed for a set of complex nested subviews.

**Your better option:**

Work with a `UITableView` instead, it has the `scrollView` methods and it handles the dynamic layouts for you very easy without all the spaghetti code.