# Why does the UIScrollView calculate a massive contentSize with AutoLayout?

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview, ios-autolayout

So I've followed all the best practices with respect to having a scrollable content view that works with autolayout (first have one direct subview of UIScrollView, add all the pin constraints, etc), especially when you have a UITextView (i.e. disable scrollingEnabled on the text view)

[for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652334/uitextview-inside-uiscrollview-with-autolayout), or just googling UIScrollView and Autolayout you'll find a lot of tutorials that rehash the same thing.

I've done all this, but am noticing that the scrollView is calculating a contentSize that does not match the contentView's height.  I have no idea why this is:

[image]

I expect moderators to point out other questions.  I looked around and nothing really matched what I'm seeing...

Comment: You say it doesn't match, so... What is the `contentView`'s height? And, is your `contentView`'s bottom anchor constrained to the bottom anchor of the scroll view, with a constant of Zero?

Comment: ha!  very bizarre.  Somehow in the storyboard the constant was set to 680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, it was DonMag's comment that solved it.  Unknowingly, the constant was not set to 0, which explains why the contentSize.height WAS 680pt larger than the content.