# How can I add a fixed view under dynamic uitextview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITextView Object. I want to add another view under but the TextView fills the whole screen. Couldn't find how to do. What I want to do is show a fixed view when the scroll is finished. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use tableviews adding the view in the last row/section of the table view. It is difficult to help you if we don't see how you implemented your code.

Comment: Please review [ask]. From your question, we have no idea what you mean by *"dynamic UITextView"* or *"fills the whole screen"* or *"when the scroll is finished"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the textViews own scrollView for scrolling.
Instead setup an outer scrollView that contains the textView and your footerView (either by embedding in a stackView or by setting up your own constraints).
Getting text and scrollView resizing right can be tricky.
Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914046/921573) for details.

To summarize:

> 1. Add UIScrollView inside the main view in Storyboard
> 2. Add UIView inside the UIScrollView
> 3. Add UITextView inside the UIView (the view added in step 2)
> 4. Make sure "Scrolling Enabled" of UITextView is unchecked
> 5. Add 4 constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom) on UIScrollView
> 6. Add 4 constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom) on UIView (the view added in step 2)
> 7. Add "Width Equally" constraint on UIView (the view added in step 2) and the main view
> 8. Add 5 constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom, height) on UITextView. After this step you shouldn't get any errors and warnings on constraints.
> 9. Add UITextView height constraint IBOutlet on the ViewController. `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewHeightConstraint;` and connect it in Storyboard
> 10. Change the UITextView height constraint programmatically. `self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = [self.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;`